# CSS layout, how to make sections one after the other?

Tags: css

```css
 

body {
 background-color: #E6E6FF;
}
#header {
    padding-top: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100px;
}
#footer {
    text-align: right;    
}
#navMenu {
 background-color: #42424C;
 text-align: center;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: #42424C;
        padding:10px;
}
#leftside {
    width:200px;
    float:left;
    min-height: 500px;
     border-style: solid;
 border-color: #42424C;
}
#content {
        
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: #42424C;
 padding: 10px;
        min-height: 500px;
}
```

```html
  


    <div id="header">Header</div>
    <div id="navMenu">Menu</div>
    <div id="leftside">left side</div>
    <div id="content">content</div>
    <div id="footer">footer</div>
```

how it looks:
[image: problem]
My Problem:
See the red arrow in the picture the #content goes over the #leftside I want the #content to start after #leftside how can I do this? Also I wand #leftside and #content to always be the same height, I can not set fixed height because thre can be a lot of stuff in content and it might be long and I want my #left side to last until #content ends and #footer begins is it possible to do so? Any help appreciated!

Comment: The wording in your question is confusing...  do you want it to come AFTER the left side div...  or next to it?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by js like this

```
<script>
var content=document.getElementById('content').style.height;
var leftside=document.getElementById('leftside').style.height;
if(left>right)
{
document.getElementById('content').style.height=leftside;
}
else
{
document.getElementById('leftside').style.height=content;
}
```

If you don't care for IE6 and IE7 users, simply use display: table-cell for your divs:

[check here](http://jsfiddle.net/CTsFF/)

Note the use of wrapper with display: table.

For IE6/IE7 users - if you have them - you'll probably need to fallback to Javascript.

Comment: Even considering IE6 or IE7 should be prohibitted by law.

Comment: I really don't think so otherwise we still are trying to find a way to show multimedia on Nexus lol

Answer (score 0):

One way of keeping the sidebar the same height as the content is to display them as table-cell. This way the two cells will always be the same height.

Using your code above, I have added a few extra lines of CSS and wrapped the main content in a div wrapper.

```css
body {
  background-color: #E6E6FF;
}
#header {
  padding-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
}
#footer {
  text-align: right;
}
#navMenu {
  background-color: #42424C;
  text-align: center;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #42424C;
  padding: 10px;
}
#leftside {
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 500px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #42424C;
}
#content {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #42424C;
  padding: 10px;
  min-height: 500px;
}
.main-wrap {
display: table;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 500px;
}
#leftside,
#content {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">Header</div>
<div id="navMenu">Menu</div>
<div class="main-wrap">
  <div id="leftside">left side</div>
  <div id="content">content</div>
</div>
<div id="footer">footer</div>
```

You could also look at CSS [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)